# Cannot use css 3d transforms in Opera 12.16

Tags: css, opera, css-transforms, webkit-perspective

the NVIDIA Quadro FX 1500 graphic adapter on my old XP system is fairly old and seems not on list of supported Chrome HW; however, I managed to enable 3d transforms on Chrome, using this:

1. in address bar, go to chrome://flags/
2. Override software rendering list -> enable

Now I'm looking for a similar trick to enable 3d css on Opera 12.16.

Testing is done with this page: http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/Qh8YV/ which displays a simple 3d rotated div.
This test succeeds on FF, Safari, Chrome, but fails on Opera.

Similar result with this simple test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            background-color: gold;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;

            perspective: 300px;
            perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -o-perspective: 300px;
            -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -webkit-perspective: 300px;
            -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
        .inner {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;

            transform: rotateY(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotateY(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        is this 3d?<br>
        is this 3d?<br>
        is this 3d?<br>
        is this 3d?<br>
        is this 3d?<br>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The div is unrotated on Opera.

In Opera's error console I found these messages:

```
        perspective is an unknown property
              perspective: 300px;
  ------------------------^ Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:12
        perspective-origin is an unknown property
              perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -------------------------------^  Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:13
        transform-style is an unknown property
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
  ----------------------------^ Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:14
        -o-perspective is an unknown property
              -o-perspective: 300px;
  ---------------------------^  Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:16
        -o-perspective-origin is an unknown property
              -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  ----------------------------------^   Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:17
        -o-transform-style is an unknown property
              -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -------------------------------^  Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:18
        -webkit-perspective is an unknown property
              -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  --------------------------------^ Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:20
        -webkit-perspective-origin is an unknown property
              -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  ---------------------------------------^  Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:21
        -webkit-transform-style is an unknown property
              -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  ------------------------------------^ Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:22
        Unrecognized function
              transform: rotateY(45deg);
  --------------------------------------^   Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:35
        Invalid value for property: transform
              transform: rotateY(45deg);
  --------------------------------------^   Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:35
        Unrecognized function
              -o-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -----------------------------------------^    Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:36
        Invalid value for property: -o-transform
              -o-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  -----------------------------------------^    Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:36
        Unrecognized function
              -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  ----------------------------------------------^   Inlined stylesheet  3d.html:37
        Invalid value for property: -webkit-transform
              -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
  ----------------------------------------------^
```

Chrome, Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Opera:
[image: Opera]

Questions:

1. DOES Opera support 3d transforms?
2. If yes: what can the problem be - the old HW?, the code?
3. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Just tested this: Opera: about:config / acceleration / Enable Hardware Acceleration: 1 (value was 0) -> no effect

Comment: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) shows Opera 15 supporting 3D transformations using the `-webkit` prefix. It doesn't give any information about versions prior to 15 though.

Comment: Wow, this is strange: Help / About tells me this: Version 12.16 / Build 1860 / Plattform Win32 / OS Windows XP.
The Executable is from July 9 2013 - just 2 weeks old; Update Checker tells me that the version IS the latest. BUT: there is a Opera_15.0.1147.148_Setup.exe available. Is this the official version? If so, why the update checker tells me that I have the latest version? Do I miss something? Since I use Opera for compatibility checks, I'm not comfortable installing a version which is not recommended by the update mechanism.
Anyway - I'm quite certain Opera 12.x should support 3d css.

Comment: This is because these are two different branches that are maintained separately. Opera 15 is a completely new browser based on Chromium, the old Opera engine (Presto) was dropped, together with a lot of other features. http://my.opera.com/securitygroup/blog/2013/07/02/opera-15 Oh and no, Opera 12 (and earlier) does *not* support CSS 3D Transforms. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me post this as an answer too, so that it's visible at a more prominent place.

Opera 12 and earlier do *not* support CSS 3D Transforms, they are available as of Opera 15, which is more or less a new browser based on Chromium.

So no need to worry, there is no workaround for this, it's simply not supported.

http://my.opera.com/securitygroup/blog/2013/07/02/opera-15
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/

Comment: Oh! - I didn't expect that. HTML5 has been around for some years.

Comment: @Gisela Nobody really rushed to implement 3D Transforms, outside of WebKit where it was first implemented in 2009. IE was the next browser to ship with support, in IE10 in August 2012; Firefox got support last October — around the same time as the last Presto-based Opera release shipped.